# vue assets image not load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

src/assets/profile.jpg

[image]

`<v-img src="../assets/profile.png" aspect-ratio="2.75"></v-img>`

not load

I do not work. What is the reason?

By the way,

If you specify img tag src, the image will be output.

Comment: The extension png is an error. It will not work even if you change it to jpg.

Comment: Try to use `<v-img :src="require('@/assets/profile.jpg')" aspect-ratio="2.75" ></v-img>` instead

Comment: To. Jns
Thanks!

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer with an explanation (as you asked for)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to bind your image path to the `src` property and then you have to wrap the path in `require('@/assets/profile.jpg')` to let webpack know that this is a dependency.

So as mentioned as a comment, change your code to this: `<v-img :src="require('@/assets/profile.jpg')" aspect-ratio="2.75" ></v-img>`

Answer (score 5):

This Work for me...

```
<template>
      <img :src=logo>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        logo: require('@/assets/profile.png')
    })
}
</script>
```